# Count self intersection for a curve Grasshopper/Python

Tags: python, grasshopper, rhinoceros

I'm trying to find the number of occurrences of self-intersections for a curve in Grasshopper but I don't understand why some points aren't taken into account in my occurences list.

I used Curve|Self (CX) to find the intersections and then count() in Python.

For instance, points "2", "15" and "37" are the same, but, python find 1 occurence for point 2 and two occurences for 15 and 37 (and not 3 for the three points !). Do you know this problem? 
How do I find the self intersection of the curve and right occurences by using Grasshopper and/or Python?

Thank you

Comment: For better help, provide the code please.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Rhino.Geometry.Intersect as its

a = []
itsevents = its.Intersection.CurveSelf(x, 0.01)
for event in itsevents:
    a.append(event.PointA)
print len(a)
```

look at this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqwvr.png) and it would make more sense

remember to set your x input typehint to `Curve`